# Python: import all submodules' method?

Tags: python

I organized my helper method into this way:

[image]

All the methods are used in the current file, so I need to import them like this:

```
from helpers.utility_helper import *
from helpers.app_helper import *
from helpers.gmm_helper import *
from helpers.plot_helper import *
```

So I can directly use methods in each of the submodule. For example, use `my_helper()` instead of `helpers.utility_helper.my_helper()`.

But this looks quite verbose, is it possible to combine them into one line? Something may look like

`import * from helpers/*`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use explicit imports instead of importing whole:

```
from helpers.utility_helper import my_helper, your_helper
```

This will help to avoid mistakes.

For short names you can use *as*:

```
import helpers.utility_helper as util
import helpers.app_helper as app
import helpers.gmm_helper as gmm
import helpers.plot_helper as plot
```

It is quite normal practice.